# enumvalues of stdregprov returns different list than regedit

Tags: vba, registry, wmi

I am using the following VBA code to return the key values in ODBCINST\ODBC Drivers.  Below is the list if I look in regedit then the list this returns
I can't find the list this returns anywhere.

```
Dim strComputer As String, strKeyPath As String, strDrivers
Dim objRegistry As Object, arrValueNames, arrValueTypes
Dim iCounter As Integer
strComputer = Environ$("computername")
strDrivers = ""
strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers"
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
objRegistry.EnumValues HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrValueNames, arrValueTypes
For iCounter = 0 To UBound(arrValueNames)
    strDrivers = strDrivers + arrValueNames(iCounter) & vbCrLf
Next iCounter
MsgBox (strDrivers)
```

here is the list from RegEdit
[image]

here is the list from the code:
[image]

I don't get it?

Comment: Is there missing code, or are you using a reference to a library?  As-is, your example doesn't run.

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit version of Windows?  If so, [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/305097/how-to-view-the-system-registry-by-using-64-bit-versions-of-windows) might apply.

Comment: @ashleedawg, it's the body of an MS Access function.  I left out the error checking.  references are pretty standard, vba, access 14 object library, Ole Automation, office 14 access database engine object library and ms scripting runtime

Comment: @asheedawg, your second note is spot on.  it's a 32 bit version of access on a 64 bit machine.  The code in the vba is getting the list from the WOW6432Node even though I'm pointing to the base "software" node.  Thank you.  I'm not sure how I'm going to handle this yet.  I'm trying to automate making a dsn when a user needs it instead of having the client have to install it.  I've got thoughts though